# Why can't the Flash fly while he is running at the speed of light?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

Why can't he fly? It only makes sense because of the lift he would get, especially at the speed of light.

And why wouldn't he transform into light instead? I mean he could go around the universe in a blink of the eye, or use it as a burst.

Comment: In the Tv show he cant moved the speed of light, hes in the low mach's still

Comment: Please edit this question to avoid unnecessary expression and be more understandable (hint: add some **sentence case** and **punctuation**.

Comment: He wouldn't even need to reach the speed of light to get airborne - if he could reach escape velocity (MUCH slower than light) he would escape the Earth's gravitational pull and fly off into space. The thing is, he attains this fantastic speed by *running,* which requires boots on the ground. As soon as he jumps or otherwise loses contact with a surface to run on, he begins *decelerating* thanks to gravity (and wind resistance, etc.) To be sure, he can probably jump hella high (or hella far) but it's still not quite flying.

Comment: If he's able to achieve relativistic velocity then staying on the surface of Earth is the least of his problems. See https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/ for what happens to a baseball at 0.9c.

Comment: In the comics he's been shown to run through the vacuum of space.
As to why he doesn't transform into light: Speedforce.

Comment: he needs a pedal powered plane.the with appropriate gearing he must be able to achieve super sonic speeds. Similarly if he thought about it he could run a dynamo based power plant too. Superheros are so selfish sometimes.

Comment: As fast as he's moving, he could probably just run on the air particles.

Comment: Hi, scientist here- why would approaching the speed of light transform you into light? Let me rephrase that- is there something in the comics or elsewhere which indicates that this is what occurs?

Comment: The [Effects of a human moving faster than sound](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/effects-of-a-human-moving-faster-than-sound) in an atmosphere would be bad. It's the same for whatever handwaved reason he doesn't turn into a trail of shredded cheese after about three feet.

Comment: @DubMan [There's an XKCD for that too](https://what-if.xkcd.com/3/)